# I can't center multiple headers while also finding them in the table of contents

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to center multiple different headers but I cant center more than one without creating subheaders

```
<center>
# **Poster**
</center>

## Hello

<center>
# Penny
</center>

<center>
## **Plan**
</center>
```

Everything shows up in the table of contents right now but only Poster and Plan are centered. I had to put 2 # in front of plan to make it centered.